# How to Include a JSP Fragment into a JSP Page while forwading from Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jsp-fragments

First, Please suggest me if my question heading is not correct.

Moving on to question:
Say I am having below components:

`search.jsp` - A JSP Page with a Form to Submit Data

`Search.java` - A controller Servlet having both `get()` and `post()` defined separately so that it can acts as a dispatcher for path *`/search.jsp`*

`searchResults.jspf` - A Fragment with some JSTL code to show up the *Search Results*

What I want here is for every *POST* request the controller servlet has to do its calculation, set results as Request Attributes and than - *forward the request to the view `search.jsp` that should include the Fragment after its own  codes*.

So that, I can have a View Defined in such a way as:

```
search.jsp
+
searchResults.jspf
```

on a single page.

Problem is, I can either do Forward or Include with the dispatcher as I don't know how can i *Include* a fragment while forwarding to a JSP into it.

Let me know if I need to post some code if necessary, or need any corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your search.jsp embed your searchResult.jsp using jsp:include:

```
<jsp:include page="searchResult.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Exemple:
1. The servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet", urlPatterns = "/myForwardTest")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("search.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          doPost(request, response);
    }
 }
```

2. search.jsp:

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>In search resust</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    Search.jsp embed searchResult.jsp
   <jsp:include page="searchResult.jsp" />
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. searchResult.jsp

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
   <body>
     in searchResult
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: How can I make sure it gets included *only* when coming from Servlet's POST method??

Comment: have you tried it? When you forward the request from controler, at this time i don't think there's a difference between post and get ... how do you forward your request ?

Comment: I tried it, no problem at all.if you want i have am exemple?

Comment: Thank You, I got a way around, I used JSTL `c:if` that looks for a `requestAttribute` say `showResult` , if comes `true` it will `include` the `searchResults.jspf` else nothing will happen, when forwading Request through GET, I am setting it as `false` in servlet's `doGet()` method, whereas I am setting it as `true` in `doPost()`!! I think its a right way. . Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can include your jspf in your jsp like below:

```
<%@include file="searchResult.jspf" %>
```

you can set a statement to execute a certain section only if a particular test evaluates to **true** .

**Ex:**

```
if(.....==true){
<%@include file="searchResult.jspf" %>
}else{
<%@include file="someOther.jspf" %>
}
```

Comment: I would like to use JSTL or EL tags rather than JSP code, if you could help me pls. . .

Comment: You can learn JSTL and EL more through these links given below. They have given examples for using each and every tag in JSTL.
**JSTL-->** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm
**EL-->** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm